# Scaling Elasticsearch down to single-node

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to scale Elasticsearch from multiple nodes down to one node?

I have a 3-node cluster that is way overkill for the amount of data being logged.
To scale it down, I set "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._ip" to the IP nodes 2 and 3 to get all the data on to one node.

I stopped Elasticsearch on node 3, and the cluster remained healthy.

In preparation to turn off the second node, I adjusted the cluster settings to require a quorum of 1 and make sure it was persistent instead of transient.  Then I stopped Elasticsearch on node 2.

Finally I went on to node 1 and set discovery.type to single-node and restarted Elasticsearch.

Elasticsearch is throwing an error:

```
cannot start with [discovery.type] set to [single-node] when local node {node1.customer.local}{r5tnzHEYRN6TNPNur9jpqA}{PjBDleWmTeSvkRUuUNWVWw}{10.132.135.55}{10.132.135.55:9300}{dilm}{ml.machine_memory=33730138112, xpack.installed=true, ml.max_open_jobs=20} does not have quorum in voting configuration VotingConfiguration{tlbB7vMgQXOzvO36iboqOQ,r5tnzHEYRN6TNPNur9jpqA,s1fLGX7RS│fL
GX│tGpFh2xPZkkIw}
```

How can I scale down to one node?